# Prefered way to declare events

Tags: c#

I am fairly happy with my understanding of the .NET event model. I think I might be misunderstanding a small nuance of the system.

When I started out putting events into my classes I would use the standard way like so:

```
public event EventHandler<MyEventArgs> MyEvent;
```

This meant that anything subscribing to the event would need a method like:

```
void HandleThatEvent(object sender, MyEventArgs args){...}
```

Which is nice, but I found that I would rarely care about the sender, so it made a lot of method signatures bloated.

So I switched to declaring my own delegate types

```
public delegate void MyEventHandler(SomeClass argument);
```

Which cut down on clutter, but left me with a small problem when it came to writing handlers:

```
eventImplmentor.MyEvent += HandleThatEvent;
.
.
.
void HandleThatEvent(/*oh, um, what arguments does it take? Intellisense isn't telling me*/)
```

So I would have to go back to the declaration of the delegate and look and then go back and write them in, or compile it and wait to be told.

So now instead, I'm just using `Action`, `Action<T>` or whatever template fits.

```
public event Action<SomeClass> MyEvent;
```

So that I can hover over the event and be told what parameters it expects.

My question, after all that: Is there a best practice for declaring events in C#? Should I go back to the `EventHandler<T>` way, or is `Action<T>` acceptable?

Comment: Don't forget to make sure the handler is locally copied to where you fire the event, always want to do this for thread safety.

Comment: You can write your own smart, mean & lean type-safe events in encapsulated code but anything you publish should follow the standard pattern or it will just confuse the users of your class (and apparently some tools too).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For simple, internal event handling, there are those that simply use `Action` or `Action<T>`, as you are proposing. I tend to use the standard pattern, including the Sender, even for internal events, because you never know when you might later want to expose a class or event, and I would not want the penalty of having to refactor the event method just to make it public.

I do agree with you that the event handling signature is a bit heavier than it should be for simple scenarios, but it is well designed to handle incremental migration as additional event arguments could become necessary over time. Overall, I would stick with the standard pattern, especially since, as you noted, you only get proper IntelliSense support if you do.

For what it's worth, I put some time into this and came up with a different event handling pattern: [Event Signature in .NET — Using a Strong Typed 'Sender'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1046016/event-signature-in-net-using-a-strong-typed-sender). The goal here was not to remove the Sender, but to make it generically strong typed as `TSender` instead of weakly typed as `System.Object`. It works very well; however, one does lose IntelliSense support when you do this, so there is an unfortunate trade-off.

Overall, I would stick with the standard pattern, but it is interesting to think about potentially better ways to do this.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to your SO question. It's very interesting. I still don't understand why it's so important that the sender is mandatory. Most of the time I don't care about the sender. Is it just some arbitrary MS rule?

Comment: No, of course you can declare your delegates however you like.  It's .NET policy to always include the sender, and it's not entirely a bad idea at that.

Comment: @Neil: I understand that it use useful sometimes, but I don't get the policy of always doing it - especially since MS recommend doing events their way. One of the things I really like about events is the ability to decouple classes. If I'm including the object, then it's coupled back up again. If it's just a CLS compliance thing then I can live with that.

Comment: It's coupled back up again only if you use the sender object, otherwise it doesn't matter what gets put as the value of sender since you don't use it.  Dependency exists only if you need there to be a dependency.  I see where you're coming from, and if object sender disappeared from all code from any server on the planet, I wouldn't stay up nights.

Comment: Yes, you can send 'null' as the sender if you really want... But, by including the Sender, the event handler itself could unsubscribe if it wanted to. Overall, though, I would say that knowing the source of the event is usually pretty important.

Comment: @MattEllen: the importance of always including the sender is that the sender is always included.  Consistency.  If I see sender, e then I have to spend exactly zero time figuring out what the signature implies about the event handler when working on it.  It's there if I want it, and can be ignored if I don't.